# Декодирование url-текста с процентными последовательностями

Tags: python

Я передаю через form слово "Привет", которое перекодируется в "%CF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2%21".
Как мне раскодировать "%CF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2%21" назад, в "Привет"?

Comment: Похоже на windows-1251, но где вы её откопали вместе с cgi!? И, кстати, это не «Привет», а «Привет!»

Comment: Как его раскодировать? Как это сделали Вы?

Comment: Я передавал текст через input HTML

Comment: https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/

Comment: Откуда взялась форма? В общем, код в студию

Answer (score 1):

Есть же специально обученный модуль `urllib`:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

txt = "%CF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2%21" 
res = unquote(txt, encoding='cp1251') #обратите внимание на кодировку
print(res)
```

> Привет!